# What is the equivalent for "Consideration" (English common law) in Spanish speaking countries?

Tags: contract-law, common-law, translation, mexico

Consideration is a *concept* of English common law and is a necessity for simple contracts.

**Consideration** may be thought of as the concept of value offered and accepted by people or organisations entering into contracts. Anything of value promised by one party to the other when making a contract can be treated as "consideration": for example, if A signs a contract to buy a car from B for $5,000, A's consideration is the $5,000, and B's consideration is the car.

Translating into "*Consideración*" just does not work at all, there must be a *concept* to explain the same in Latin-American Countries. For instance, how do you call this in Mexico, Argentina, Chile, Peru, Bolivia, Colombia, etc.? Or in Spain?

Any hint is very welcome.

Comment: As you figured out, consideration is a concept from English common law, and none of those countries are common-law countries. Yet you assume that there "must be a concept to explain the same". Why do you assume that? Furthermore, why do you assume it would be the same concept across so many countries?

Comment: In common-law systems, consideration is required for all contracts, not merely simple ones. I don't know what term a Spanish-speaker describing a common-law system would use. I don't believe that there is any closely analogous concept in civil-law systems.

Comment: @MSalters presumably it is possible to discuss English common law in those countries.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Scottish law is at least partially a common-law system, and consideration is *not* a requirement for all contracts in Scottish law.

Comment: @MSalters If the concept exists, it will be the same in all countries - they are all ex-Spanish colonies, and will all have borrowed heavily from Spanish law in their legal systems.

Comment: Do you want the name of the equivalent concept in those countries (which may not exist), or do you want the word that Spanish lawyers use when discussing the English concept in Spanish?

Answer (score 4):

> What is the equivalent for “Consideration” (English common law) in Spanish speaking countries?

Prestación.

Perhaps not all Spanish speaking countries adopt a one-word term, but the notion of consideration definitely exists in civil law. It is quite mistaken to presume that the concept is unique to common law systems.

The Civil Code of both [Spain](https://boe.es/buscar/pdf/1889/BOE-A-1889-4763-consolidado.pdf) (see art. 1257) and [México](https://www.oas.org/dil/esp/C%C3%B3digo%20Civil%20Federal%20Mexico.pdf) (art. 1793) are in terms of "*transmission or transfer of rights*", which fits the meaning of *consideration*.

The Civil Code of Spain in its art. 1254 refers to "*[consent] to give something or perform [prestar] a service*" (brackets added for clarity), whence the term *prestación* qualifies as *consideration* in several --if not all-- types of contract. In fact, article 1274 literally mentions "*prestación or promise*".

Comment: I suppose contraprestación is _also_ a consideration. (See  https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrato, Elementos reales). And I suspect those terms are closer in meaning to _ performance_. That's old Roman law, see e.g. _Exceptio non adimpleti contractus_

Comment: @MSalters "*I suppose contraprestación is also a consideration*". Correct, similarly to how transactions, contracts, etc. involve a party and a counterparty. "*I suspect those terms are closer in meaning to _ performance_*". *Performance* is closer in meaning to *compliance*, for which the word in Spanish law is *cumplimiento* and is contemplated in arts. 1256-1258 of the Spanish Civil Code.

Comment: In Mexico (and several other Latin-American Countries), two words are utilized to describe the very same concept covered by "Consideration":

`Consideration =` **Prestación and Contraprestación**.

_The Prestación is offered and the Contraprestación is given in return._ Just like a "Consideration".

Thank you all !

Answer (score 1):

> <sub>**Consideration** is a *concept* of English common law and is a necessity for simple contracts.</sub>
>
> <sub>Consideration may be thought of as the concept of value offered and accepted by people or organisations entering into contracts. Anything of value promised by one party to the other when making a contract can be treated as "consideration": for example, if A signs a contract to buy a car from B for $5,000, A's consideration is the $5,000, and B's consideration is the car.</sub>
>
> <sub>Translating into "*Consideración*" just does not work at all, there must be a *concept* to explain the same in Latin-American Countries. For instance, how do you call this in Mexico, Argentina, Chile, Peru, Bolivia, Colombia, etc.? Or in Spain?</sub>
>
> <sub>Any hint is very welcome.</sub>

[spain](/questions/tagged/spain)

There is no required tradition to be followed (in line with [this](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/42779/27096)).
In a *negocio* of *oneroso* and *lucrativo* nature, if you still want to make it both fancier and clearer, it's explicitly enough to write about the ***bienes y/o derechos controvertidos***.

In your example, B's car is all of the *bienes controvertidos de parte de B en el negocio*.

With regards to a, whenever used, *contraprestación pecuniaria*, either *A aporta 5.000,00 dólares `PAÍS` en concepto de bienes controvertidos* (for cash in hand, wire transfer, etc.) or *A transmite un derecho de cobro de 5.000,00 dólares `PAÍS` en concepto de bienes controvertidos* (in case of broader credit).

*En virtud del presente contrato*, you can add to it if you want.

Answer (score -1):

### There isn’t one

Common law [contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contract) law requires this, civil law [contract](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_obligations) law doesn’t.